# QFile::resize behaves differently in Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
#ifdef _WIN32
    QString fileName("G:\\sampledir\\file1.txt");
#elif __linux__
    QString fileName("/home/dheeraj/sampledir/file1.txt");
#endif
    QFile *file = new QFile(fileName);
    if(!file->resize(32))
    {
        cout<<"ERROR in resize"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the directory I have specified is already there and the file does not exist. In windows the call `"file->resize(32)"` creates the file in disk and returns true. But in ubuntu, the call  `"file->resize(32)"`  returns false.

What might be the reason? What is the actual expected behavior?

The documentation for `QFile::resize` too is not very definitive. It says This function 'can'  fail if the file doesn't exist.

I am using Qt 5.9.2 in Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have you tried to use the [`error`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#error) function to find out what the problem might be? Or possibly to check `errno`?

Comment: Have you tried creating the file if it doesn't exist before resizing? The documentation is pretty clear that it might fail if the file does not exist.

Comment: You need to check if the already exist. If not, create it. Otherwise like Qt docs says: **[Warning: This function can fail if the file doesn't exist.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#resize-1)** Behavior of Windows and Linux Filesystems are different, so you need to take care about this.